# How to turn off Nikon D5000 live view timer?

Tags: nikon-d5000, live-view

I am frustrated with my Nikon D5000.

When I click 'Live View', there is a timer by the corner that limits it to 30 seconds only. After that, it automatically shuts off. This is frustrating especially for video recording. I looked through *everywhere* in the menu, and nothing. How can I turn it off completely?

Comment: Is there a way to disable the timer completely? Like when using the Guide? The maximum time it allows me to stay on LV is 5min :(

Answer (score 2):

**You can't** and, while I understand why you are asking, even if you could you would not like it.

Your battery would most likely run out in less than an hour unless your sensor overheats first. The limits is meant to protect the camera not to frustrate you.

Answer (score 1):

If its anything like the D3100, there's a "Timing" menu under the shooting menu in setup and then its a "custom" timing mode.

Answer (score 1):

This restriction is made intentionally not to overheat the sensor. D5000 DSLR is not made for shooting videos. Live view mode is very similar to that.